# How to get Client Machine or device Unique Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

For my website I want to get some unique id of the device from where user is navigation to site. 
device can mobile/laptop/desktop.

Is it possible in asp.net to get some unique id.

I need this id to Build cache key so that that cache will only available to that device.

Thanks
Dalvir

Comment: A session id isn't enough?

Comment: yes I am using session id that works but my case is to share cache on two domains. so I ma using query string to pass session id from one domain to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a static variable somewhere of type `Guid` and initialize it with `Guid.NewGuid()` should be enough. This will be unique for every environment.

Then use `guidVariable.ToString()` and add that to your cache key?

Comment: I want to share that cache for two domains so if user opening both domain in his system then that should be available. So in this case guid is not the solution as i have to share that id in query string to get cache on second domain. so this key can be used by other users. so will not be a solution for my problem

Comment: how about putting a unique key in the app/web.config of your application? and use the same key for those instances which should share the key?

Comment: But this key will be for application not for users. i need some unique key based on users. right now i am using session id so to share this I am using query string so if any other user use this query string with same values then cache will be accessible by him. i don;t want so.

Comment: Well you didn't really described that scenario in your question ;) 
Anyways, one way to secure that "session token" would be to use an encrypted cookie. If you really have different websites in different domains and not only sub domains, you might have to deal with CORS to send the cookie to the other domain.